# When dynamically scaling a table (in a bootstrap vue tab section) one section does scale, another does not, can someone explain this to me?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Ive created a Component that represents two tabs (register and login),
[The tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/101yR.png)

In both tab-components ive called the same piece of code to re-adjust the styling when the pagewidth is small enough, which seems to work in the register section but does nog in the login section

[The code for the form in the login tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VerV3.png)

[The script and styling of the login tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2mrd.png)

Im new to stack-overflow so if I made any mistakes with my question please let me know!

Edit: I miswrote Mounted in my original code, changed it to mounted and now it works when the page is reloaded, but my goal is to let it change dynamically when the screen is resized (same code works fine for the Register part)

Comment: in the script code i saw the mounted hook declared with uppercase letter "Mounted". Please make lowercase "mounted" and try again

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I changed Mounted to mounted (I used mounted with small m in my register tab which does work dynamically)
Only now it works when i refresh the page, but not when i change the width of the screen myself (without refresh)